# key with multiple arrays in the json file

Tags: json

Good morning,

I have a json file where my `Text` key needs to have several arrays, for example:

```
text = ["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"];
```

I tried to do it as follows, but it is giving a syntax error, how would it be in this case?

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Text": [
      "texto1",
      "texto2",
      "texto3",
      "texto4",
      "texto5",
      "texto6",
      "texto7",
      "texto8"
    ],
    [
      "texto1",
      "texto2",
      "texto3",
      "texto4",
      "texto5",
      "texto6",
      "texto7",
      "texto8"
    ],
    [
      "texto1",
      "texto2",
      "texto3",
      "texto4",
      "texto5",
      "texto6",
      "texto7",
      "texto8"
    ],
    [
      "texto1",
      "texto2",
      "texto3",
      "texto4",
      "texto5",
      "texto6",
      "texto7",
      "texto8"
    ],
    [
      "texto1",
      "texto2",
      "texto3",
      "texto4",
      "texto5",
      "texto6",
      "texto7",
      "texto8"
    ],
    [
      "texto1",
      "texto2",
      "texto3",
      "texto4",
      "texto5",
      "texto6",
      "texto7",
      "texto8"

    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi because you have nested arrays you’ll have to put your
arrays in another array. The proper syntax should be

```
{
    "text": [
        ["a", "b", "c"],
        ["a", "b", "c"]
    ]
}
```